# python does not execute shell command "mail" properly

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, email

I use the following bash code to send email:

```
echo abc | mail -s Subject abc@def.com
```

It works fine. Now I want to use the same command in python, so I write the following:

```
call(["echo abc" "|" "mail", "-s Subject", "abc@def.com"], shell=True)
```

This python code does not send me the email and when I call the python script using

```
$python email.py
```

I get the following information from shell

```
No mail for rex
```

How does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `subprocess.communicate` as suggested elsewhere is a much better approach.  You should avoid using `shell=True` for the reasons described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).  But to answer your question why your call doesn't work, the problem is that you've broken the shell string up into rather arbitrary strings.  If you pass the whole command as one string, it *should* work on Unix-y platforms at least.

```
call(["echo abc|mail -s Subject abc@def.com"], shell=True)
```

See the details [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).  But such usage is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I use the code provided by icktoofay and it works. But I also appreciate the educational details you posted.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for `echo` and piping between commands if you're using Python.
You can start a process and use the `communicate` method:

```
import subprocess

def send_message(recipient, subject, body):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, recipient],
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate(body)
```